# How to set up Android.mk to perform nested build

Tags: android, android-ndk, ndk-build

I am trying to figure out how to set up one `Android.mk` to depend upon another.  The latter builds a native code shared library, and the former has a JNI library that depends on the shared library.  Let's call these `shared_lib` and `service`.

Right now, the `Android.mk` for `service` contains code like this:

```
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ../../../shared_lib/libs/armeabi/libshared_NDK.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

This works, but only if `shared_lib` was already built.  Building `service` does not build `shared_lib`.

I wrote a shell script that first builds `shared_lib` and then builds `service`.  But it seems like it should be possible to use the build system to do the build tasks.

I have tried to use `$(call import-module,...)` but haven't found any syntax that works.  There is so much magic in the makefile path expansion that I can never predict what will happen.  For example, with this code added to the Android.mk for `service`:

```
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
SL_DIR=$(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../shared_lib
$(call import-add-path,$(SL_DIR))
NDK_MODULE_PATH := $(SL_DIR)
$(call import-module, jni)
```

This didn't work at all; I got this error result:

```
/Users/steveha/devel/android/ndk/build/core/build-binary.mk:450: warning: overriding commands for target `obj/local/armeabi/libshared_NDK.so'
/Users/steveha/devel/android/ndk/build/core/build-binary.mk:473: warning: ignoring old commands for target `obj/local/armeabi/libshared_NDK.so'
/Users/steveha/devel/android/ndk/build/core/build-binary.mk:489: warning: overriding commands for target `libs/armeabi/libshared_NDK.so'
/Users/steveha/devel/android/ndk/build/core/build-binary.mk:489: warning: ignoring old commands for target `libs/armeabi/libshared_NDK.so'
make: *** No rule to make target `../../shared_library/jni/com_dts_SourceFile.cpp', needed by `obj/local/armeabi/objs/dts-shared-jni/com_dts_shared_SourceFile.o'.  Stop.
```

It looks like `import-add-path` is messing up the variables, thus causing the C++ source files to be searched in a wrong place.  But `import-module` fails without it.

Also, running `ndk-build clean` in the directory of `service` fails with an error if you run `ndk-build clean` on `shared_lib` first.  Since the `.so` file is listed as a local source file, it is an error for it not to be present.

`ndk-build` is built on top of `make`, and `make` has a single global namespace, and everything I have tried for making one `Android.mk` build another `Android.mk` has had problems like this.  The best way seems to be to explicitly call `ndk-build` to get a fresh instance of `make` and thus a separate namespace.

Is there any way to set things up so that `ndk-build` on `service` will build `shared_lib` first?  Bonus points if the `ndk-build clean` case described above also works properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never did find a pure "make" solution.  Instead, I wrote a Python script to build each module in turn.  It is simple and robust to run each `ndk-build` in its own process.